# Can you put named credential username and password in the endpoint

Tags: apex, callout, namedcredentials

The short- is there any way to use named credential merge fields in the actual named credential callout's endpoint (in the query string)

There is an api that I need to make a callout to in salesforce with an endpoint similar to this:

http://some.api.com?api_id=12345&api_key=somelongapikey

I didn't want to hard-code the api_id or api_key in my code, so I set up a named credential with the following information:

```
Name- Test
Identity Type:  Named Principal
Authentication Protocol: Password Authentication
Username    my api_id
Password  my_api_key
Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header- checked  
Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body -checked
```

And here is my code that is saying it is an invalid URI:

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Test?api_id={!$Credential.Username}&api_key={!$Credential.Password}');
req.setMethod('GET');
HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);
```

The api won't let me put the api key or id in the headers; it has to be in the endpoint's query string.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Could always use a custom setting to pull the credentials into your code

Comment: Custom labels, and custom metadata if you want to source control them like-named credentials.

Comment: Using custom settings worked like a charm. Thanks!